# Migrating from bash to zsh - where are the packages I installed?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

I am new to a lot of this, so forgive me if I don't understand this 100%. I have just installed macOS Big Sur, then installed a few tools in my bash terminal (`homebrew`, `nvm`, `npm` + `node`, `yarn`, `gatsby cli`) - then I decided I'd try out zsh for the first time! So I switched to zsh.

However: Now, when I do `nvm -v`, or `npm -v` etc. it just always gives me `Command not found` - but it *can* find `brew` via `brew -v`.

I'm sure this is something very basic, but being new to this I don't understand what needs to be done or what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Not 100% sure myself, as I use tcsh, but bash and zsh should be able to share a common set of config files. Or they can use different files. My guess is that you have the zsh config file(s) present in your homedir, so they’re being used. You would need to copy over the homebrew lines from your bash config to the zsh config, or just delete the zsh file(s) if you’re not using them, and let zsh fall back on the bash files. You would need to do an `ls -ald ~/.*` and add that output to your answer for more exact help from a zsh/bash expert.

Answer (score 0):

Use `brew reinstall <package>` to reinstall your packages and it will show you instructions on what to put into your `.zshrc` file.